# Spectral projection measure of normal operators

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Suppose $M, N$ are self-adjoint operators, let $E_M$ be the spectral projection measure of $M$ and $E_N$ be the spectral projection measure of $N$.

If we denote $E_{M-N}$ by the spectral projection of $M-N$, does the following relation hold?

$E_{M-N}=E_M-E_N$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's actually kind of hard to find any example where the equality holds. The equality does hold when $M,N$ are both projections with $N\leq M$. I cannot imagine another situation where it holds.

If your equality held,
you immediately get that $E_N\leq E_M$ (since projections are positive). So $E_N$ is a subprojection of $E_M$. This implies that $\sigma(N)\subset\sigma(M)$. That's far from enough, though.

Even when the operators commute, it is easy to find counterexamples. For instance let
$$
M=\begin{bmatrix} 1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix},\qquad N=\begin{bmatrix} 0&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Then
$$
E_M(\Delta)=M\,\delta_{1}(\Delta),\qquad E_N(\Delta)=N\,\delta_1(\Delta),
$$
so $$ E_M(\Delta)-E_N(\Delta)=(M-N)\,\delta_1(\Delta),$$ which is not positive (nor projection-valued).

Comment: Professor Argerami, I have a question: why $E_M(\Delta)=M\,\delta_{1}(\Delta)$ hold? According to Conway's book , we have $E_M(\Delta)=\chi_{\Delta}(M)$.

Comment: Yes. And since $M$ is a projection,  $1_\Delta(M)$ is $M$ if $1\in\Delta$ and $0$ otherwise.

Comment: I still don't understand. How to use the functional calculus, we can map $\chi_{\Delta}$ to $\chi_{\Delta}(M)$, how to compute  $\chi_{\Delta}(M)$?

Comment: You use the spectral theorem. The spectrum has two points.

Comment: Would you mind explaing it in details? I am quite unfamilar with the spectral theorem and I cannot use it correctly

Comment: We are applying functional calculus to diagonal matrices: $$ f(M)=\begin{bmatrix}f(1)&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}.$$ And, you are asking questions about spectral projections and you are "quite unfamiliar" with the spectral theorem? Well, get familiar, quick.

Comment: I made a mistake. You assume that $M$ is a concrete diagonal matrix. I thought is was a normal element.

Comment: Actually, $E_{M-N}(A)=E_M(A)-E_N(A)$ can never hold for all Borel sets (in dimension $1$ and higher) simply because $E_{M-N}(\mathbb R)=1$ and $E_M(\mathbb R)-E_N(\mathbb R)=0$.